# Website crashed after installing ZPanel on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, dns, wordpress

I was hosting a Wordpress on my Ubuntu 12.04 server but I messed it up by installing a ZPanel on it, which totally crashed the website.

Is there any way to fix it? Either uninstall it or?...

I can't access the site now either by IP address or my domain name address.

And I tried to enter `zpanel.mydomain.com` which should be the login page for the ZPanel, but it keeps saying couldn't find DNS server.

I configured my domain DNS settings, I tried using A type and CNAME with host set to ZPanel and point to my IP, but it doesn't work.

Any advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove zpanel and reset http.conf and vhost.confg file:

**httpd.conf**

Set your directory of your website to load:

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/mywebsite.com/public_html"

on last line of httpd.conf remove the line:
Include /etc/zpanel/configs/apache/httpd.conf

**vhost.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
     ServerAdmin support@my-website.com
     ServerName my-website.com
     ServerAlias www.my-website.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/my-website.com/public_html
  ErrorLog  /var/www/html/my-website.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/html/my-website.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Replace my-website.com with your web domain

Comment: Please don't post self-promotion into answers.